# testing if front window is active

Tags: window, applescript

A given app (Skim) provides a snapshot window that floats above other windows whether or not the snapshot is selected as "active".

```
    set window_name to name of front window
```

identifies the snapshot window as the front window whether or not it is active.

How can a script determine if the active window is the snapshot window?

Answer (score 0):

The properties of windows in Skim doesn't get it, but it's possible by the `Accessibility Frameworks (GUI Scripting)`.

If the Accessibility Frameworks are disabled, enabled it by clicking the checkbox labeled "**Enable access for assistive devices**" in the Universal Access System Preference pane.

```
set snapshotIsActive to my checkSkimFrontWindow()

on checkSkimFrontWindow() -- this handler return true or false
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Skim"
            set frontmost to true
            delay 0.1
            tell window 1 to subrole is "AXDialog" and value of attribute "AXMain" is true
        end tell
    end tell
end checkSkimFrontWindow
```

Comment: That's great -- thanks. I'll follow-up in a separate question re how to check status and reset the checkbox if need be.